# Azure AD B2C Service to service authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c

I need service to service authentication.

I followed this documentation [Azure AD B2C s2s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

and everything looks good so far except for I am not able to acquire access token for client service in any other way rather than just explicitly calling for POST authentication endpoint.

So I am able to retrieve access token doing in code something like this:

```
var bodyContent = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "xxx"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "xxx"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://xxx/.default")

        };

        var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync("auth_url", new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyContent));

        var accessToken = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AccessTokenResponse>()
```

What I was trying to achieve is trying make it work automatically in some way using:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { builder.Configuration["MyScope"] })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

and then acquire token like this:

```
string result = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
```

instead of doing it manually like in the example above.

But whatever I am trying to do I still get  **No account or login hint was passed to the call**

Comment: Did you get this error the first time you authenticated, or the second time you accessed? Did [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524263/account-not-found-after-restart-no-account-or-login-hint-was-passed-to-the-acqu) can help you?

Comment: @Chen this link is more relevant for user flow, but I am using service to service authentication (client credentials flow)

Answer (score 1):

*Update 02/11/2022*

Seems like you're simply using the wrong method to request an authorization code

When you want a (daemon or app) service to authenticate to another service:

**Don't use** `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(); // Wrong, it uses the current logged in user for the request`

**Do use**   `GetAccessTokenForAppAsync() // Correct, it request a code via client_credentials flow`

---

Short answer: You're passing in scopes to .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() instead of the AzureAD OpenIdConnect configuration with a separate app registration attached to it.

The long answer:

*"The OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow permits an app (confidential client) to **use its own credentials**, **instead of impersonating a user**, to authenticate when calling web resource, such as REST API."* [Microsoft Docs]

This flow does not authorize with a user who initiated the request, it uses its own credentials.

Therefore, you need 3 app registrations in AzureAD B2C.

- [**1**] The front-end app registration where your users sign in
- [**2**] The app registration you will use to generate authorization codes and
  authorize scopes
- [**3**] The app registration for the service you're trying to call.

With that in place you add a new section to your AppSettings.json in the front-end (eg. name it "downstreamApi"), containing the client secret, scopes, and some default OIDC settings like Authority, and then you can then simply call

```cs
services
   .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .EnableTokenAquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
       .AddDownStreamWebApi("MyAPI", Configuration.GetSection("downStreamApi");
```

Comment: sorry, but I seem to miss why do we need front-end app registration here where the user signs in, given that there are no users, only service to service authentication is needed. (By some client id and secret or whatever)

Comment: Well, a line of code threw me of course. I assumed you'd have a front-end, since you are using the `.GetAccessTokenFor**User**Async(scopes);` method. As the name suggests, that is for a user, not for an application. Hence you receive an error because you have no active user. Does that make sense?

Comment: In other words, use `GetAccessTokenForAppAsync(scopes)` instead of the user one, and you'll probably have a working situation there.

Comment: ohh, that's a dummy mistake. Will give it a try, thx a lot

Comment: Awesome @fox112358, hoping for the best. Will you please let me know if that works? Otherwise we'd need to debug this further